# Maximize the following equation under a constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Maximize $g(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ on $x^2+y^2=9$.

Our professor had sped through it and I didn't fully understand how they arrived at the answer. Some clarification on it would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the writing below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 = x^4 + \underbrace{\big(\sqrt{9-x^2}\big)^4}_{from~constraint} = g(x)$

$${d g(x) \over d x} = 4 x^3-4 x \left(9-x^2\right) = 4x \left( x^2 - \left(9-x^2\right) \right) = 4 x^2 (2 x^2 - 9)$$

Set this function of a *single* variable $x$ to equal $0$ (for an extremum) and thus find:

$$\left\{\{x\to 0\},\left\{x\to -\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right\}$$

Then test each individually to see if it is a maximum, minimum or inflection point.  (You can also calculate second-order derivatives to solve that problem, or plot the functions...)

[image]

It is clear that $x=0$ corresponds to a local maximum, while the other solutions correspond to local minima.

By the way, the handwritten notes say "obviously $(0,0)$ is a minimum," which is false.  That point does not obey the constraints and is hence invalid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't quite understand, the values that you received are the max on the boundary of the graph or just random points on the graph? I'm quite new at this.

Comment: This approach misses the local extrema at $y=0$.

Comment: @random:  Huh?  When $y=0$, $x=\pm 3$.

Comment: From the symmetries in the original problem it follows that the local maximum of $g(x,y)$ at $(0,3)$ implies the existence of the same local maximum at $(3,0)$ and $(-3,0)$. The chosen parameterization of the upper half of the circle does show them by the value of g(x) at $x=-3$ and $x=3$, but the value of $g'(x)$ at those points is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are finding a maximum on a circle centered at the origin it makes sense to convert both equations to polar coordinates:

\begin{eqnarray} g(r,\theta)&=&(r\cos\theta)^4+(r\sin\theta)^4\\
                            &=&r^4(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)\\
\frac{dg}{dr}&=&4r^3(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)=0\\
\frac{dg}{d\theta}&=&-4r^4\cos^3\theta\sin\theta+4r^4\sin^3\theta\cos\theta\\
&=&-4r^4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\\
&=&-2r^4(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\\
&=&-2r^4\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)\\
&=&-r^4\sin(4\theta)=0
 \end{eqnarray}

So extrema should occur when $\sin(4\theta)=0$. And $\sin(4\theta)=0$ only when $4\theta$ is a whole multiple of $\pi$. Thus you must check points of the circle corresponding to multiples of $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

You should find that the minima occur when $\theta$ is an odd multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and the maxima will occur when $\theta$ is an even multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ (i.e. a multiple of $\dfrac{\pi}{2})$.

$$g\left(3,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=g\left(3,\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)=g\left(3,\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)=g\left(3,\frac{7\pi}{4}\right)=\left(\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4+\left(\pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4=\frac{81}{2}$$

$$g(3,0)=g\left(3,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=g\left(3,\pi\right)=g\left(3,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=3^4=81$$